# Regex to read a file and return the first line after the matched pattern from inside the file in Python

Tags: python, regex

Example string 1:

```
7.2.P.8.1 

Summary and Conclusion  


A stability study with two batches was carried out.
```

Example string 2:

```
7.2.S.1.2  

Structure 

Not applicable as the substance is not present.
```

I want to write a regex to fetch the first line after this form (7.2.P.8.1 ) or (7.2.S.1.2 ) or (8-3-1-P-2) or any other format(either everything will be separated by . or -) and retrieve it. So from the first
intance I need as output (Summary and Conclusion) and from the second instance (Structure). The word 'Example String' wont be part of the file content and is just given to show an example.

Maybe occasionally the format will be like:

```
9.2.P.8.1 Summary and Conclusion  

A stability study with two batches was carried out.
```

In this case also, I want to retrieve as output : Summary and Conclusion

Note: I only want to retrieve the first matching pattern from the file and not all matches, so my code should break after finding the first matching pattern.
How can I do this efficiently.

Code till now:

```
import re
def func():
    with open('/path/to/file.txt') as f: # Open the file (auto-close it too)
        for line in f: # Go through the lines one at a time
            m = re.match('\d+(?:[.-]\w+)*\s*', line) # Check each line
            if m: # If we have a match...
                return m.group(1) # ...return the value
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
import re

rx = re.compile(r'\d+(?:[.-]\w+)*\s*(\S.*)?$')
found = False
with open('/path/to/file.txt', 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        if not found:                         # If the required line is not found yet
            m = rx.match(line.strip())        # Check if matching line found
            if m:                               
                if m.group(1):                # If Group 1 is not empty 
                    print(m.group(1))         # Print it
                    break                     # Stop processing
                else:                         # Else, the next blank line is necessary
                    found=True                # Set found flag to True
        else:
            if not line.strip():              # Skip blank line
                pass
            else:
                print(line.strip())           # Else, print the match
                break                         # Stop processing
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/LQRJM4) and the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/WUq0Iv/3).

**NOTES**

The `\d+(?:[.-]\w+)*\s*(\S.*)?$` regex searches for 1+ digits and then 0 or more repetitions of `.` or `-` followed with 1+ word chars, and then tries to match 0+ whitespaces and then *capture* into Group 1 any non-whitespace char followed with any 0+ chars up to the line end. If Group 1 is not empty, the match is found and `break` stops processing.

Else, the `found` boolean flag is set to `True` and the next non-blank line is returned.

Comment: I have some issues understanding how you are using the boolean flag and the else part of the code. Would be glad if you can help me out

Comment: @ajaibiltu `found` is *False* at the start because we have not found a matching line yet. When a line is read, `if not found` block is triggered. Once the line matching the regex is found and Group1 is empty, the flag is set to *True* and `else` block is triggered. At that moment we know that we need the next non-blank line. Hence, `if not line.strip():` check is required, if the line is blank we need to skip it (use `pass`).